# Linux - signal: error: invalid use of non-static member function

Tags: c++, linux, asynchronous, signals

I originally wrote some tests to test the functionality of signals for my program. The tests proved promising, however moving the small code changes to my class in my source code has given me a few problems.

I have added two functions: `setAlarm()`, and a callback `alarm_handler`. `setAlarm()` does as it says, which is set the alarm. Once time expires, alarm handler is called which runs an execute function.

**a.cpp**

```c++
int Database::alarm_handler(int signum)
{
    dbExecSql();
}

void Database::setAlarm()
{
    signal(SIGALRM, alarm_handler);
    ualarm(500000,0);
}
```

**b.h**

```
class Database
{
public:
    int alarm_handler(int signum);
    void setAlarm();
    dbExecSql();
};
```

**error**

```
error: invalid use of non-static member function
     signal(SIGALRM, alarm_handler);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I have modified alarm_handler to be removed from my class, however am now am receiving:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘int (*)(int)’ to ‘__sighandler_t {aka void (*)(int)}’ [-fpermissive]
     signal(SIGALRM, alarm_handler);
                                  ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signal handler function (`alarm_handler`) can't be member function and should be a standalone function with C linkage.

Remove it from your class:

```
void alarm_handler(int signum)
{
    dbExecSql();
}
```

Beware that only [async-signal-safe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) functions can be called from signal handlers safely. So you need to ensure `dbExecSql()` respects that.

Comment: thanks that's good to know! I made the change you recommended, however am not getting:

error: invalid conversion from ‘int (*)(int)’ to ‘__sighandler_t {aka void (*)(int)}’ [-fpermissive]
     signal(SIGALRM, alarm_handler);
                                  ^

Comment: Seems you have `int` return type (for `alarm_handler`). it should be `void`.

Comment: coding 98% of the time makes me want to cry. thanks so much mate